# How to link taxonomy terms to view page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have enabled the taxonomy menu module and created a custom view from my vocabulary terms. However, the taxonomy menu terms are by default in the following structure [taxonomy_category]/[term-name] and link to the default taxonomy view.

How can I override the default taxonomy term links to link to my view page?I want to link the taxonomy term to this view page : products/term_id . I have downloaded taxonomy display module but either I didn't know how to configure it correctly or it doesn't work....

Anybody, who knows how can I change the links of the taxonomy terms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's a default (disabled) view that links to "taxonomy/term/term_id". You should enable that view and make the necessary changes to suit your needs.

Comment: So this view is the one taking effect even though is it disabled ? How come taxonomy_category/taxonomy_term show a page describing the taxonomy by default.

Comment: this view has no effect if it is disabled. when you enable it, it overrides the default `taxonomy/term/term_id` path and use this view instead of the default taxonomy page. now you can edit this view to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can create a view.

In the "Page Settings" you have the path.

Just put "/taxonomy/term/%" in the path.

It worked for me.